# record in Garageband with iRealPro

Tags: audio, ipados, garageband

I want to record my guitar in Garageband with tracks from iRealPro on my iPad. I plugged my guitar into my iPad audio with a guitar interface adapter.  IooAn [article](https://irealpro.com/dwkb/ireal-pro-with-garageband/) says there are small ways to do this but I can't get any of them to work. If I select send/record in iRealPro when it's finished it only saves it too a file. In Garageband, there is no Audio Interface App to choose from. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iReal Pro removed the IAA compatibility with Garageband so you need to export the audio file from the app, import it to Garageband and then record.
You can simply record with iReal Pro as well using your interface.

Comment: I did that but I didn't like the result.  The level on the backing track was too high and the level on my guitar was too low. If I raise it any higher on my Behringer U-Phoria UMC-22, then it clips. Do I need a better interface? I was playing a hollow-body with a floating pick-up, turned almost to the max.

Comment: Correction, on my iPad, I use a smaller guitar interface, "woCharger". I've had it for a while but just started using it. Maybe I need a better one.